# JOOQ: How to create MockResult for stored procedure with out parameters?

Tags: java, sql, mocking, jooq

When using the JOOQ MockDataProvider what is the correct way to build a MockResult for stored procedures?

The examples I've found show how to return results for tables and views by creating a result and record from generated table definitions and then returning them. For stored procedures I'm not sure how to build the Result.

How do I create a record that will map to the return parameter and out parameters of a stored procedure?

Is there some way to convert the out parameters on a routine to record fields?

Here is an example stored procedure that I would like to create results for:

```
DECLARE @return_value int,
        @StoredSystemId int

EXEC    @return_value = [dbo].[myProc]
        @StoredSystemId = @StoredSystemId OUTPUT,
        @UserName = 'user',
        @EmailAddress = 'user@mail.com'

SELECT  @StoredSystemId as N'@StoredSystemId'

SELECT  'Return Value' = @return_value
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [`MockDataProvider.execute`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org.jooq/org/jooq/tools/jdbc/MockDataProvider.html#execute(org.jooq.tools.jdbc.MockExecuteContext)) Javadoc:

> `OUT` parameters from stored procedures are generated from the first [`MockResult`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org.jooq/org/jooq/tools/jdbc/MockResult.html)'s first [`Record`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org.jooq/org/jooq/Record.html). If `OUT` parameters are requested, implementors must ensure the presence of such a `Record`.

An example would be:

```java
MockConnection con = new MockConnection(ctx -> {
    Field<Integer> id = DSL.field("StoredSystemId", SQLDataType.INTEGER);
    return new MockResult[] { new MockResult(DSL.using(DEFAULT).newRecord(id).values(42)) };
});

try (CallableStatement cstmt = con.prepareCall("{ call xyz(?) }")) {
    cstmt.registerOutParameter(1, Types.INTEGER);
    cstmt.execute();

    System.out.println(cstmt.getInt(1));
}
```

It would print:

> 42

Notice that both the field name and actual SQL string are irrelevant to jOOQ's `MockDataProvider` SPI. In your case, you will want additional results after the out parameters, which you can just append to the `MockResult[]` array. The important thing is that the `OUT` record is returned first.